The difference between a "for" loop and a "while" loop
This is more of a question to aid my understanding as I learn python. I am working my way through an exercise book and the following challenge was given:

Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9.
Write a function called send_messages() that prints each text message and
moves each message to a new list called sent_messages as it’s printed. After
calling the function, print both of your lists to make sure the messages were
moved correctly.

The code I wrote initially used a 'for' loop, which didn't iterate through all of the messages:
messaging = ['Hello world!', 'Keep it coming!', "Don't give up!", "I'm getting hungry!"] # list of messages to send
sent_messages=[] # list of sent messages
def show_messages(messages): #define the name of a list in function
    **for message in messages: #while loop to keep running until list has been gone through
        current_mess = messages.pop() #remove latest message
        print(current_mess) # print latest message
        sent_messages.append(current_mess) # add latest message to sent_messages

show_messages(messaging[:]) #create a copy of the messaging list so original isn't touched by using a slice
print(messaging)
print(sent_messages)`

The output for this was as follows:

I'm getting hungry!
Don't give up!
['Hello world!', 'Keep it coming!', "Don't give up!", "I'm getting hungry!"]
["I'm getting hungry!", "Don't give up!"]

However when I changed the function to have a "while" loop, it worked correctly:
messaging = ['Hello world!', 'Keep it coming!', "Don't give up!", "I'm getting hungry!"] # list of messages to send
sent_messages=[] # list of sent messages
def show_messages(messages): #define the name of a list in function
    while messages: #while loop to keep running until list has been gone through
        current_mess = messages.pop() #remove latest message
        print(current_mess) # print latest message
        sent_messages.append(current_mess) # add latest message to sent_messages

show_messages(messaging[:]) #create a copy of the messaging list so original isn't touched by using a slice

print(messaging)
print(sent_messages)

Output:

I'm getting hungry!
Don't give up!
Keep it coming!
Hello world!
['Hello world!', 'Keep it coming!', "Don't give up!", "I'm getting hungry!"]
["I'm getting hungry!", "Don't give up!", 'Keep it coming!', 'Hello world!']

I was mainly curious as to what is exactly happening i these two versions of the code to make on work and one not which may improve my understanding of loops.

You say the while loop worked correctly? It doesn't seem so. It's printing the messages in reverse order.

For loop didn't work because you removed items from the list while iterating over it.

When doing a for loop, you shouldn't change the thing that you're iterating over within the loop (it's bad practice and can lead to results like you are seeing). In the for loop version you don't need to pop the current value of messages to get it, it is given by the message variable, i.e., do:
messaging = ['Hello world!', 'Keep it coming!', "Don't give up!", "I'm getting hungry!"] # list of messages to send
sent_messages=[] # list of sent messages

def show_messages(messages): #define the name of a list in function
   for message in messages:
       print(message)  # print latest message
       sent_messages.append(message)  # add latest message to sent_messages

show_messages(messaging) 
print(messaging)
print(sent_messages)


In this corrected code, you don't even need to create a copy of the list that you pass to the function, as it doesn't get modified.

Yes, indeed - I've removed the slice copy.

For loops will run until you have iterated through everything in the thing you are iterating over. While loop runs until the condition becomes false. In your case the condition becomes false because the object is empty, this is the convention with most programming languages. This is a bit of a simplification to give you the right idea
